# Direct register access of BCM chip

Tags: pi-3

BCM2835 datasheet clearly documents register structure and access to the device.
I have not found similar document published by Bradcom for BCM2837 , but would assume it allows similar manipulations of internal registers.

Not being familiar with actual implementation of "canned" GPIO functions - YES there are **numerous function each** and every GPIO port can have, not limited to "canned" configuration,
can someone point me in the direction of Raspberry load process and actual code implementation of these function(s)  ?

Since some on this forum have hard time interpreting my QUESTIONS, 
here is a different verbage for same - **where is the "Open source" code for implementing such functions, and I not need "in github" (duh) as an answer.**

I like to have, if possible to save me time looking, the real source file  where  such function is executed.
But if it is not of common knowledge of some designer here, I'll just keep looking.
Bonus question  - why do my post DO NOT format the way I wrote them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about GPIO register access.

All current Pis have the same GPIO peripheral (although the peripheral may appear at different addresses in the memory map and different GPIO are brought out to the expansion header).

There is no reference open source implementation.

Choose any implementation from http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples which meets your definition of open source.  Generally the source code will be linked to from that page.